# If $f(x,y)$ is convex in $x$ (for any fixed $y$) and convex in $y$ (for any fixed $x$), is it convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ be a function $X\times Y\rightarrow\mathbb R$, where $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ and $Y\subset \mathbb R^m$, and $x\in X,y\in Y$.

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ is convex in $x$ for any fixed $y$, and convex in $y$ for any fixed $x$. Does it follow that $f$ is convex?

I have the feeling that it does not. But I cannot find a simple counterexample.

The assumptions of the question imply that:

$$f\left(\lambda x_{1}+\left(1-\lambda\right)x_{2},y\right)\le\lambda f\left(x_{1},y\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)f\left(x_{2},y\right)$$

$$f\left(x,\lambda y_{1}+\left(1-\lambda\right)y_{2}\right)\le\lambda f\left(x,y_{1}\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)f\left(x,y_{2}\right)$$

for any $0\le\lambda\le1$.

On the other hand, if $f(x,y)$ is convex, the following (stronger) inequality must hold:

$$f\left(\lambda x_{1}+\left(1-\lambda\right)x_{2},\lambda y_{1}+\left(1-\lambda\right)y_{2}\right)\le\lambda f\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)f\left(x_{2},y_{2}\right)$$

I tried to derive this inequality, without success:

$$\begin{aligned}
f\left(\lambda x_{1}+\left(1-\lambda\right)x_{2},\lambda y_{1}+\left(1-\lambda\right)y_{2}\right) & \le\lambda f\left(\lambda x_{1}+\left(1-\lambda\right)x_{2},y_{1}\right)\\
 & \qquad+\left(1-\lambda\right)f\left(\lambda x_{1}+\left(1-\lambda\right)x_{2},y_{2}\right)\\
 & \le\lambda\left(\lambda f\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)f\left(x_{2},y_{1}\right)\right)\\
 & \qquad+\left(1-\lambda\right)\left(\lambda f\left(x_{1},y_{2}\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)f\left(x_{2},y_{2}\right)\right)\\
 & =\lambda^{2}f\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)^{2}f\left(x_{2},y_{2}\right)\\
 & \qquad+\lambda\left(1-\lambda\right)f\left(x_{2},y_{1}\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)\lambda f\left(x_{1},y_{2}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: This is called a biconvex function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconvex_optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest counterexample is
$$f(x,y) = x \, y.$$

Comment: this example was already mentioned in the comments to my answer, and should be credited to @Theo Bendit

Comment: @becko: No, this example works on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, since the Hessian is constant.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x,y) = x^2 + x y^2$, on the set $A = \{ 1\leq x \leq 2, \  10\leq y \leq 20 \}$ (for example).

Then $f$ is convex if we fix either of its arguments, since $f''_{xx} = 2 > 0$
and $f''_{yy} = 2x > 0$ .

However, the Hessian matrix of $f$, which equals
$$ D^2 f = \left(
\begin{matrix} 2 & 2y \\
2y & 2x
\end{matrix} \right),
$$
is not positive definite, and hence $f$ is not convex on the set $A$.

Comment: +1 And now that I think of it, $f(x, y) = xy$ works for $[0, \infty)^2$.

Comment: yes indeed, it's a better looking example. I just played with the Hessian, to build something which will violate the positive definiteness, but would have positive diagonal.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks. That's indeed the simplest example.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there's a finer counterexample, but you could take any convex function defined over $X \times Y$ and restrict its domain to a orthogonally convex, but not convex subset of $X \times Y$. For example, take the $0$ function, restricted to
$$\mathbb{R} \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace \cup \lbrace 0 \rbrace \times \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}.$$ When you restrict to any horizontal or vertical line, the result is a convex function.

But I find this a little unsatisfying. I wonder if forcing the domain to be convex will make it true?

Comment: Actually, in a similar vein of pettiness, even convexity of the domain is not quite sufficient. For example, define any non-convex function along the diagonal subset $\lbrace (x, x) : x \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. I think it'll be similarly trivial to construct examples on convex sets with non-empty interiors, by exploiting boundary values. So, now I wonder, does this hold for functions defined on all of $X \times Y$?